# how to loop through a file and write to disk using a windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to know how to loop through lines with colons in a text file using a Windows batch file and get the second token and write that token to disk.

eg:-

> Name : -I$HAN-

```
 I want -I$HAN- to write to disk.
```

Comment: Usiing "tokens=1* delims=:" you are half way there with the for /f command.
See `For /?` or visit [ss64.com for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "file=name_of_input_file"
set "outfile=name_of_output_file"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (%file%) do echo %%a>>%outfile%
```

Comment: you should add some explanatory text to this. Code-only answers are frowned upon

Answer (score 0):

As you also have a space either side of the colon and probably don't want it adding to your output, therefore try:

```dos
@Echo Off
Set "file=name_of_input_file"
Set "outfile=name_of_output_file"
(For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1* Delims=: " %%A in ("%file%") Do Echo=%%B)>"%outfile%"
```